# Is custom property documentation in tsx files possible?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, tsx

Similar to how the ide helps with descriptions when i document a function like so.

```
/**
 * My Test fn
 * @param a - some description here
 */
function Test(a) {}
```

I would like the ide to show a description in the following scenario but I cannot get it to say anything except "(JSX Attribute) test: boolean"

```
interface TestProps {
    /** Some comment here */
    test: boolean;
}
class TestComp extends React.Component<TestProps, any> {
    render() {
        return <span>{this.props.test}</span>
    }
}

const test = (props) => (
    <div><TestComp test={true} /></div>
)
```

Is there any way to get it to show the description when helping out with the test property?

Examples: [image]

[image]

Notice the bottom image has -some description here and top doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed with TypeScript 2.4 and VSCode 1.14:

[image]

VSCode 1.14 ships with TS 2.4 included. You can make sure TS 2.4 is active by checking the TS version in the lower right corner of the VSCode status bar

[image]

You can also use a newer version of TS in an older version of VSCode by following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions)

Please [let us know](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) if you run into any other issues with this

Comment: VSCode 1.14 is not officially released yet, but you can preview it in the insiders builds: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders We should ship 1.14 early next week

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript uses JSDoc. `/* Some comment here */` is not valid JSDoc. `/** Some comment here */` is the right way to do it.

## Bug in VSCode / TypeScript

Beyond the fact that the comment was wrong. There was a bug that failed to show docs that has been fixed in TypeScript / VSCode.

## More on JSDOC

http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html